# Copying a value from a reference count to an owned box

Tags: rust

I'm using reference counters in the code (`std::rc::Rc`) to keep track of a record from multiple places within a data structure. However when i take the record out of the data structure I want to convert it to an owned pointer.

Ideally I would like to destroy all my reference counts and *move* the underlying record to an owned pointer (without having to *copy* it out of the Rc) but I don't think this is possible because there is no way to guarantee that I have destroyed all the Rc-s.

So instead I am trying to create the owned pointer by boxing up a clone. Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

#[deriving(Show, Clone)]
struct Person {
  age: int,
  name: ~str,
}

fn main() {
  let x = Rc::new(Person{ age: 31, name: "Alex".to_owned() });
  let y = box (*x).clone();

  println!("{0:?}", *x);
  println!("{0:?}", y);
}
```

But when I compile this I get

```
work.rs:11:19: 11:20 error: unexpected token: `.`
work.rs:11   let y = box (*x).clone();
                         ^
alex@alex-xubuntu:~/src/sandbox$ rustc work.rs && ./work
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this doesn't work?

Note that the following *does* work, but at the cost of an additional copy:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

#[deriving(Show, Clone)]
struct Person {
  age: int,
  name: ~str,
}

fn main() {
  let x = Rc::new(Person{ age: 31, name: "Alex".to_owned() });
  let y = (*x).clone();
  let z = box y;

  println!("{0:?}", *x);
  println!("{0:?}", z);
}
```

Here's my rustc version:

```
alex@alex-xubuntu:~/src/sandbox$ rustc --version
rustc 0.11-pre (e454851 2014-05-08 06:11:37 -0700)
host: i686-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I filed [#14085](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/14085) about making the error messages better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `box` allows placement; loose EBNF:

```
"box" [ "(" expr ? ")" ] expr
```

If the placement value is missing, it is taken to be `::std::owned::HEAP`; for example, `box foo` is equivalent to `box () foo` and `box (HEAP) foo`.

This is tripping up your case, because it is interpreting `*x` as the placement value, and then it is trying to parse `.clone()` as an expression, which is not legal.

You must write it instead in a manner that takes this into consideration:

```
let y = box () (*x).clone();
```

Comment: That said, shouldn't `x.clone()` work without explicit dereference (`*x`)? I thought that autoderef should make it unnecessary for any kind of smart pointer.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: without the explicit deref it would be calling `Rc<T>`'s `clone` (i.e. just bump the ref-count and return the same `Rc<T>` pointer), not the `clone` of the `T` interior.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot that `Rc`s should be cloned in order to share ownership. Thanks for the reminder :)